# What's the meaning of bolded phrase?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

He knows **his Shakespeare.**

I think this sentence is not grammatical,plz anyone suggest me the explanation (if any)

Comment: It's informal but grammatically correct. We use the possessive this way in "His geography is dreadful", "How is your English?" and "If we remember our Greek mythology..." "She knows her onions" is more informal.

Comment: Give me any source, i want to know about these usages of possessive adjective..

Comment: You can find explanations of _know one's onions_ and _know one's stuff_ online, but I can't find anything for _know one's [subject]_. You just have to accept that it's a way of saying 'know a lot about [a subject]'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that he knows about Shakespeare. It's an idiom. We sometimes say, "Bob really knows his auto mechanics" rather than "Bob really knows about auto mechanics", or whatever subject. It's more emphatic than saying "knows about X".

If we're talking about a woman, we'd say "She knows HER ". The pronoun refers to the person doing the knowing.

Comment: What's that idiom??

Comment: I mean, "Bob knows his <subject>" is an idiom.

Comment: How can i find it on a dictionary?

Comment: @sam Dictionaries normally list definitions of words, and only coincidentally list idioms. I don't know a name for a book that lists idioms. But in this case, just for example, look at this page: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/KNOW. Definition 4 gives the idiom. But it doesn't describe it as an idiom or say much of anything more about it.

Answer (score 2):

The use of a possessive pronoun (my, his, your, etc) after 'know' and before the subject is documented in the Oxford English Dictionary:

> KNOW
>
> 9. a.III.9.a To be conversant with (a body of facts, principles, a method of action, etc.) through instruction, study, or practice; esp.
>    to have practical understanding of (a science, language, profession,
>    etc.); to have learnt by study or practical experience; to be versed
>    or skilled in; to acquire skill in, to learn (obs.).
>
> 1639 Massinger Unnat. Combat i. i. Wks. (Rtldg.) 27/1 Nay, if a velvet
> petticoat move in the front, Buff jerkins must to the rear, **I know my
> manners**.
>
> 1872 L. Carroll Through Looking Glass ix. 192 Of course **you know your
> ABC.**

(OED, 2nd ed, 1989)

Answer (score 1):

**know one's stuff** is an English idiom, which you can find as a dictionary entry [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/know%20one%27s%20stuff).

Perhaps it is acceptable to be creative by treating "stuff" as a variable and thereby substituting different items for it?